# Presenting modal view controller in viewDidLoad when in landscape leaves a messed up

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I'm presenting a view controller modally from viewDidLoad once the app starts, but when the device (or simulator) is in landscape when the app opens, the modal vc displays incorrectly. When I trigger the modal vc after a delay, it looks just fine, leading me to think that it is caused by displaying the modal controller as the view under it is adjusting to the new orientation. I can't really describe what happens, so here's a screenshot: http://skit.ch/np2g. (I'm too new of a user to embed an image)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is too early.  Try presenting it in `viewDidAppear:`.